# Mark a block of characters in VI/M ex command

Tags: vim, vi

It's quite straitforward for VI/M to mark a block of lines from Mth line to Nth line ready to delete, cut & past, or copy & paste.

```
:M,N d
:M,N m p
:M,N t p
```

If it's further required for VI/M to mark a block of characters from Ith character of Mth line to Jth character of Nth line, is it possible to accomplish **similarly** to the above?

**@EDIT**

Except the next answer asked for `visual block mode`, how about the option on typing a succinct ex command?

**@EDIT 2**

To clarify the meaning of **a block of characters**:

- a **square block** of characters, addressed by `visual block mode`, directly called upon by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> in `normal mode`
- a **zipzag area** of successive characters, addressed by `visual character mode`, directly called upon by pressing <kbd>v</kbd> in `normal mode`
- a **rows region** of successive lines, addressed by `visual line mode`, directly called upon by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> in `normal mode`. In this case, the handy solution in `ex mode` has been illustrated above when this topic was originally raised.

**@SOLUTION**

Selecting abitrary **zipzag area** of successive characters from line M, column I to line N, column J in `ex mode` exactly like in `visual character mode` :

mark:

```
:normal! MggI|vNggJ|
```

delete:

```
:normal! MggI|vNggJ|d
```

yank:

```
:normal! MggI|vNggJ|y
```

move to line X column Y

```
:normal! MggI|vNggJ|dXggY|p
```

copy to line X column Y

```
:normal! MggI|vNggJ|yXggY|p
```

**@SOLUTION 2**

Selecting abitrary **square block** of characters from line M, column I to line N, column J in `ex mode` exactly like in `visual block mode` :

mark:

```
:execute "normal! MggI|\<C-v>NggJ|"
```

delete:

```
:execute "normal! MggI|\<C-v>NggJ|d"
```

yank:

```
:execute "normal! MggI|\<C-v>NggJ|y"
```

move to line X column Y

```
:execute "normal! MggI|\<C-v>NggJ|dXggY|p"
```

copy to line X column Y

```
:execute "normal! MggI|\<C-v>NggJ|yXggY|p"
```

Comment: Ugh, explain a bit better what it is you're trying to do. The M, N, J and ... don't really help. What do the lines you've written in your example do? Are those M and N somehow important? Also, do you want to do this in vi or in vim (most often vim is installed nowadays).

Comment: How to construct an ex command in vim to delete, cut or copy & paste a specified block of successive characters located anywhere in a file?

Comment: If for example you wish to delete/yank every line that starts with ":M,N ..." I would do it with a regex, I think. If it's only something I need a few times, and the number of rows is known, with a macro.

Comment: in a nutshell, i need the same functions in ex mode to select any positioned beginning and ending of a block of characters as in the visual mode; plus to delete, move or copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use visual block mode from an ex command mode using `normal!`: for example, to select a block (line, column) from (42, 10) to (54, 20) and yank it (both lines must have at least 20 characters or `virtualedit=block` should be set):

```
execute "normal! 42gg10|\<C-v>54gg20|y"
```

. It is very straightforward way to do this, useful only in scripts.

Note that this command has at least following side-effects:

1. Setting marks `'<`, `'>`, `'[`, `']`, `''`.
2. Moving a cursor.
3. Changing registers `@"`, `@0`.
4. Adding one item to the jumplist.
5. Overwriting previous visual selection.
6. Altering `v:count` and `v:count1` variables.

Comment: Great, thx! Although failed to repeat your example for `visual block mode`, i succeeded in `:normal! 42gg10|v54gg20|y` for `visual mode`.

Comment: @sof You must write `:execute`, double-quotes and `\<C-v>`, or instead use “real” `<C-v>` that can be obtained by pressing `<C-v><C-v>` in ex mode. **Do not do the latter if you are writing scripts.**

Comment: Thx for the clarification. i tried again, exactly as described: `:execute "normal! 42gg10|\<C-v>20|54gg"`, but the selection was rather the block `[(42,1),(54,10)]` than the expected `[(42,10),(54,20)]`.

Comment: i finally figured out that the positioning for both the head and the tail character either in `visual mode` or `visual block mode` should collectively conform to `LINEggCOLUMN|`, so `:execute "normal! 42gg10|\<C-v>54gg20|"` worked out the problem.

Comment: Hi, ZyX. Could you modify the answer to correct this minor issue? Then i'll be very glad to accept it.

Comment: @sof Yeah, line before column. It works on my setup because I have `set nostartofline` in the vimrc and thus `gg` is not moving to the first column. If this option was kept default, I would have been observing the same behavior. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+V enables visual block mode, then you can use the arrow keys to select the block.

Comment: "set virtualedit" also deserves to be mentioned when talking about virtual block selection.

Comment: Trivia: You can also block-select by [quadruple](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#gui-mouse-select) clicking and dragging… ;)